# Signout button in android fragements not working? Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, kotlin

```
package com.app.myproject.Fragments

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.app.myproject.LoginActivity
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*

import com.app.myproject.R
import com.app.myproject.RegisterActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_settings.*


/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 */
class SettingsFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        view.findViewById(R.id.signout_button).setOnClickListener {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
            val intent  = Intent(this@SettingsFragment.context, LoginActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            startActivity(intent)

        }
    }
}
```

This is my code. I'm using firebase for the user accounts. I have my settings form in a fragment like this https://prnt.sc/rvs5yn

When I click the button signout nothing happens. I was following some code I found on stackoverflow on how to get intent to work on fragments.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I m not familiar with kotlin.. but I think that you have to create an object of view. And at the end of the code . You need to return the view object. Try this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is unreachable since you wrote it after the return statement, then, you have to access the inflated view from the onViewCreated method.

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false)

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    view.findViewById<View>(R.id.signout_button).setOnClickListener {
        ... // Paste your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. I've gone ahead and updated my code on my above post. But I am now getting an issue with the "findViewById"

It says "type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun <T : View!> findviewbyID (id: int) : T!
T! Please specify it explicitly."

Comment: Yes you have to specify the type of the view. To handle a click event you can simply cast it to View. I've updated my code

Comment: Thank you very much! Can't believe I didn't think of that. So for every button, label id and other widgets. I should write view.findviewbyid<view> then the widget name? Inside all other fragments if I want to call xml widgets?